# JMETER This site does not specify a policy in the P3P header ERROR

Tags: cookies, jmeter, header, p3p, http-status-code-429

I am trying to hit this URL https://subdomain.example.com in JMeter and recorded using the Blazemeter Chrome extension has all the necessary config elements but get an error:

HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1031
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Date: Tue, 20 Aug 2019 01:21:35 GMT
Expires: 0
p3p: CP="This site does not specify a policy in the P3P header"

I have tried coping the Header Cookies from Browser Header Response which works for sometime but then start throwing an error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply. In the end I figured out that no limitation for number of calls implemented.
Now come to answer this is how I managed to work this:

1. Opened the page in chrome and from the header section copied all the header elements into the header manager hard coded.
   First time it fails and returns **p3p: CP="This site does not specify a policy in the P3P header"** but also return the update variable value needed for next request which I extract and used in the next and subsequent Requests. The way I was able to find out which variable is changing by using the string comparison of 2 Response Headers

[image]

[image]

This was a difficult one but somehow worked with very minor change I also added the Header Manager to each request for safer side.

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status Code 429 Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) description:

> The HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response status code indicates the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").
>
> A [Retry-After](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) header might be included to this response indicating how long to wait before making a new request.

So there are following options:

1. Your server is overloaded, in this case there is nothing you can do here apart from reporting the error as the bottleneck
2. Your script doesn't have proper [correlation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) implemented, i.e. you're sending recorded hard-coded values instead of getting dynamic parameters
3. Your server doesn't allow such amount of requests from a single IP address within the given timeframe, you could try implementing [IP Spoofing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter/) so your server would "think" that the requests are coming from the different machines.

Comment: Hi @DmitriT    I am trying to call this webpage in JMeter https://shop.coles.com.au/a/a-national/everything/browse but I get HTTPCode 429 same thing happen when I open the same page in web browser but browser auto redirects multiple pages and eventually opens the web page

Some of the Requested cookies changes the values but I am not able to get this one right I have tried all the possible options
Redirect automatically, Follow Redirects, Use KeepAlive and Browser-compatible headers Please help me